# Formatting in inline figure

Tags: floats

I have a figure which is inline with text:
[image: inline figure]

However, after making a new page, the formating of inline maintains (it should reset):

[image]

How can I reset the formatting there?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}


%Set packages to use
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}




%Set commands to use
\geometry{left=3cm, right=3cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}






\begin{document}

\textbf{Dr. John Doe, President of blabla Inc.}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{shutterstock-651447943.png}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}Test text Test textTest text Test textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest text

\newpage
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`wrapfig` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) the optional parameter *number of narrow lines* is described, which controls the number of narrow lines. You can set this to 6 for example to cover only the lines of the section with the `wrapfigure`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 %Set commands to use
\geometry{left=3cm, right=3cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Dr. John Doe, President of blabla Inc.}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{shutterstock-651447943.png}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}Test text Test textTest text Test textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest text

\section{Test section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

\section{With number of narrow lines}
\textbf{Dr. John Doe, President of blabla Inc.}

\begin{wrapfigure}[6]{r}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{shutterstock-651447943.png}
    \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}Test text Test textTest text Test textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest textTest text

\section{Test section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]